# Given a Group G, of order 21, acting on X of size 13. I was asked to show the action has atleast one fixed point.

Tags: group-theory

I proceeded as follows:

Orbit - Stabilizer theorem forces the size of the orbits to be divisors of $G$.
Therefore, orbit sizes are of $1$,$3$, or $7$.

Then, since the orbits partition the set $X$,
$X$ must be a combination of the distinct orbits
$\Rightarrow$ $13 = t+3u+7v$.

And I would expect to find no combination with $t=0$ to solve this.

However in this occassion this didnt happen.
What is another approach to this sort of question?

Comment: $13=3\cdot 2 + 7\cdot 1$. And so $X$ given by the disjoint union of $2$ orbits of size $3$ and one orbit of size $7$ (which can be realized as quotients of $G$) is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More explicitly, for $G = (\mathbb{Z}_3, +) \times  (\mathbb{Z}_7,+)$ we can find a transitive action on $\mathbb{Z}_3$: $(g,f)x = g+x$, and on $\mathbb{Z}_7$: $(g,f)x = f+x$. Then we construct an action of $G$ on a disjoint union $\mathbb{Z}_3 \cup \mathbb{Z}_3 \cup \mathbb{Z}_7$. The idea belongs to @freakish.